# C++ expected constructor, destructor, or type conversion before '(' token

Tags: c++, constructor, sdl, destructor

I know you may regard this post as another duplicate, while it's not. It's not a duplicate because my code is different than others, and nobody else's post (that I have seen) has solved my problem.

Here is my code:

```
#include "sprite.h"

SDL_Surface * SPRITE::screen;
int player;
void DrawPlayer(int x, int y) {
    SDL_Rect rect = {x,y,20,20};
    SDL_FillRect(SPRITE::screen, &rect, 0x00CC00);
}
DrawPlayer(20,20);
```

The error is on the line `DrawPlayer(20,20);`

Comment: What line are you getting the error on?

Comment: Sorry, I'll edit the original post.

Comment: Why is it up to *you* to decide whether this is a duplicate? Being a duplicate isn't about having literally the same phrasing of your code or question, but about addressing the same *problem*.

Comment: You are aware that you cannot call a function outside of a function, right?

Comment: ....aaand now it's a duplicate of a million questions about the same problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not calling `DrawPlayer()` from within any function.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot have your call to `DrawPlayer` outside of any method. The call must be inside a class method or a global method.

Answer (score 2):

```
Try this:

#include "sprite.h"

SDL_Surface * SPRITE::screen;
int player;
void DrawPlayer(int x, int y) {
    SDL_Rect rect = {x,y,20,20};
    SDL_FillRect(SPRITE::screen, &rect, 0x00CC00);
}

int main()
{
    DrawPlayer(20,20);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

`DrawPlayer` needs to be in `main` or another function.

Answer (score 1):

How can you call a function when not in a function body?